# How to make gameobjects that work both offline and online?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I have been revisiting an old Unity project and have added many mechanics to the single-player side. Eventually, I'll need to make these mechanics compatible with the online multiplayer side (I use Photon PUN2 for the backend).

To make objects such as the main player capable of sending and receiving data over the network I often end up creating two different versions of the same scripts (eg. "FPSController" and "NET_FPSController"). These scripts are almost identical, except that the networked version includes some RPC calls, Photon callbacks, and may require additional references to external objects to function properly.

I'm looking for a better solution to avoid duplicating so much code and create more "universal" objects. I already thought about using interfaces, but given the vast number of networked objects, creating a single interface that fits all of them is not a simple task.

What would be the best approach to overcome this issue and create a more efficient and maintainable solution for handling "Universal" objects in the context of multiplayer networking? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be a job for inheritance. Create a base class with all of the bits that are the same in separate functions then create classes that inherit from this class with just the specialised code.